# Transform to linear functions

Tags: data-transformation

I'm taking an intro data science course, and we are being asked to apply transformations to data to get linear functions to apply a linear regression.

Is the basic idea as follows? Say, I have two variables $y,x$, and when I plot them, it looks almost like $y \approx \log x$. Do we "transform" this to a linear function by exponentiating both sides, so $exp(y) = x$, and now define some other function like $y' = exp(y)$, so we have a transformed linear function, $y' = x$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Given that $y \approx log(x)$, both transforms $log(x)$ and $exp(y)$ are candidates. Next you need to do fit two models: y with log(x) and exp(y) with x. Then check the residuals. The model with residuals closer to normal distribution with lesser change on the variance should be selected.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer, but fitting y with log(x) would not be a linear model.

Comment: A lot of people misunderstand the meaning of "linear" in linear model. Linear here means linear with regression coefficients, instead of covariates. For example, $Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1log(x) + \epsilon$ is linear model. $Y=\beta_0 + X exp(\beta_1)$ is not linear model.